# Which priorityClass has higher priority in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

As per the official documentation -[K8s Priority](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/guaranteed-scheduling-critical-addon-pods/#marking-pod-as-critical), the `system-node-critical` is ever higher in terms of priority then `system-cluster-critical`.

However, when compared the integer value the `system-node-critical` has -ve value(`-100000`) as priority and system-cluster-critical has '`2000000000`'.

And the priority is interpreted as 'higher integer value' is 'higher priority'. So can pods with `system-cluster-critical` evict `system-node-critical` pods ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign pods a priority class, which is a non-namespaced object that defines a mapping from a name to the integer value of the priority. The higher the value, the higher the priority.

A priority class object can take any 32-bit integer value smaller than or equal to 1000000000 Reserve numbers larger than one billion for critical pods that should not be preempted or evicted.
Here the integer value of the system-node-critical has -ve value(-100000) and system-cluster-critical has '2000000000'.It means  system -cluster- critical value is greater than one billion so critical pods that should not be preempted or evicted and system-node-critical can be evicted.

The information below which is derived from the [document](https://mohaamer5.medium.com/kubernetes-pod-priority-and-preemption-943c58aee07d) authored by Maha Amer might be helpful to you

**There are two default high-priority classes set by Kubernetes**

> **system-node-critical**:This priority class has a value of 2000001000 and is used for all pods that should never be evicted from a node.
> Examples of pods that have this priority class are sdn-ovs, sdn
>
> **system-cluster-critical**: This priority class has a value of 2000000000 and is used with pods that are important for the cluster.
> Pods with this priority class can be evicted from a node in certain
> circumstances.  For example, pods configured with the
> system-node-critical priority class can take priority. However, this
> priority class does ensure guaranteed scheduling. Examples of pods
> that can have this priority class are fluentd, add-on components like
> descheduler, and so forth.

Larger numbers are reserved by PriorityClasses such as
system-cluster-critical (this Pod is critically important to the
cluster) and system-node-critical (the node critically relies on this
Pod). system-node-critical is a higher priority than
system-cluster-critical, because a cluster-critical Pod can only work
well if the node where it is running has all its node-level critical
requirements met.